# SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '`'

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, pdo

I'm using PHP 7 on SQL Server 2008 using PDO sqlsrv and i create a function for insert like this:

```
  public function insert($table, $values,$error_msg = "Error executing query."){
                try {

                    $vals = array($values);
                    $fieldnames = array_keys($vals[0]);
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table;

                    foreach ($fieldnames as $key => $value1) {
                        $fieldnames[$key] = '`'.$value1.'`';
                    }
                    $fields = "( ".implode(" ,", $fieldnames)." )";
                    $bound = "(:" .implode(", :", str_replace('`', '', $fieldnames))." )";
                    $sql .= $fields." VALUES ".$bound;
                    $this->query = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
                    $error_msg=$sql.json_encode($vals);
                    foreach ($vals as $val) {
                        $this->query->execute($val) or die('Error Code: '.$error_msg);
                        $this->rowcount=$this->query->rowCount();
                    }

                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                   echo ('There was a problem with inserting to database: ' .$e->getMessage());
                }
    }
```

but when i call this function like this:

```
        $sql = array('ppic_mo' => $manufacturing_order_no,
               'work_area' => $work_area,
               'item_number' => $item_number,
               'item_description' => $item_description,
               'machine_no' => $machine_no,
               'quantity' => $quantity,
               'material_required' => $material_required,
               'date_from' => $date_from,
               'date_to' => $date_to        
        );
        $conn->insert('ppic_ps',$sql,"0125181711");
```

I got this error:

> There was a problem with inserting to database: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '`'.

I tried to use native insert like this and it works totally fine.

```
  $query = "INSERT INTO ppic_ps(ppic_mo,work_area,item_number,item_description,machine_no,quantity,material_required,date_from,date_to) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
      $stmt->bindParam(1,$manufacturing_order_no);
      $stmt->bindParam(2,$work_area);
      $stmt->bindParam(3, $item_number);
      $stmt->bindParam(4, $item_description);
      $stmt->bindParam(5,$machine_no);
      $stmt->bindParam(6,$quantity);
      $stmt->bindParam(7, $material_required);
      $stmt->bindParam(8,$date_from);
      $stmt->bindParam(9, $date_to);
      $stmt->execute();
```

any idea why this happen guys?

Comment: can you `var_dump()` the created query that is executed inside your insert function?

Comment: actually i tried that function in mysql and works totally fine but this time i need to use sql server 2008 as my database. i haven't 'var_dump' it yet but as i think it worked in mysql and it should work also in sql server. but now i am wrong.

Comment: `var_dump` it first, maybe it will solve your problem because in your error is says your sql query has an incorrect syntax.

Comment: How i can `var_dump` it? because it goes to `catch`{ } block

Comment: after this line `$sql .= $fields." VALUES ".$bound;` add `var_dump($sql);`

Comment: string(281) "INSERT INTO ppic_ps( ``ppic_mo`` ,``work_area`` ,``item_number`` ,``item_description`` ,``machine_no`` ,``quantity`` ,``material_required`` ,``date_from`` ,``date_to`` ) VALUES (:ppic_mo, :work_area, :item_number, :item_description, :machine_no, :quantity, :material_required, :date_from, :date_to )" There was a problem with inserting to database: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '`'.

Comment: try removing the character ` in your query

Comment: i tried to remove it but it says: string(299) "INSERT INTO ppic_ps( `ppic_mo` ,`work_area` ,`item_number` ,`item_description` ,`machine_no` ,`quantity` ,`material_required` ,`date_from` ,`date_to` ) VALUES (:`ppic_mo`, :`work_area`, :`item_number`, :`item_description`, :`machine_no`, :`quantity`, :`material_required`, :`date_from`, :`date_to` )" There was a problem with inserting to database: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Tried to bind parameter number 65536. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters.

Comment: i believe you didnt bind your parameters for your query

Comment: hmm but in mysql it works totally fine bro. i used it in my previous project. in my created select function it works totally fine also. it looks like this: ` public function select($prepared_sql,$values = array(),$error_msg = "Error executing query."){
                    $this->ERROR_MSG = 'Error Code: '.$error_msg;
                    $this->query = $this->conn->prepare($prepared_sql);  // PREPARE SQL STATEMENT
            
                    $this->execQuery($values); // EXECUTE QUERY

            
                    return $this->query;
                }`

Comment: here is my `execQuery` : `   public function execQuery($values = array()){
                    $this->query->execute($values) or die($this->ERROR_MSG);
                    $this->rowcount = $this->query->rowCount();
                }`

Comment: that is because your select function doesnt have `parameters`. in your insert its a different story.

Comment: delete and update also work bro. heres the code: `public function update($sql_statement,$values,$error_msg = "Error executing query."){
                    try {
                        $vals = array($values);
                        $this->query = $this->conn->prepare($sql_statement);
                        foreach ($vals as $val) {
                            $this->query->execute($val) or die('Error Code: '.$error_msg);}} catch (PDOException $e) {
     echo ('There was a problem with updating records to database: ' .$e->getMessage());
                    }
                }`

Comment: public function delete($prepared_sql,$values = array(),$error_msg = "Error executing query."){
                    $this->ERROR_MSG = 'Error Code: '.$error_msg;
                    $this->query = $this->conn->prepare($prepared_sql);
                    $this->execQuery($values);
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solve this issue by eliminate the `` in the

```
foreach ($fieldnames as $key => $value1) {
       $fieldnames[$key] = '`'.$value1.'`';
}
```

because sql server dont execute the query when field have `` but MySql does. for example, in MySql this query run:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(`field1`,`field2`) VALUES(?,?)
```

but in SQL Server 2008 in doesnt run.